# Windows 7 internet explorer 8 can't download some files

Tags: internet, internet-explorer-8

Bought new HP desk top and internet explorer 8 will not download some files.  Other computer with same softwre will download.

For example it will not  download this file  no  errors  or messages .http://browse.azamaraclubcruises.com/shoreExcursions/brochure/view.do

Please assist in what setting it may be different.

Comment: Got a sample date I can try?

Comment: What do you mean by "will not download"?  As in, what actually happens when you try to download one of these troublesome files?  Are all these "some files" also PDFs (like the example given)?  Do you have a PDF reader installed on this new system?

Comment: Alzamara Journey September 23 2012 -- Works for me on Vista/Firefox

Comment: I suspect that IE 8 isn't properly lashed into a PDF reader.

Comment: That site also does seem to like 3rd party download managers/accelerators very much either.  But @DanielRHicks' example data works fine with Win7/IE9 here, if I skip my manager.

Comment: @techie007 -- I always go around my manager.  The less he knows the better.

Comment: Oops, I meant to say it DOESN'T like download managers. ;)

Comment: Works fine here in Win7/IE 9. If it's a new desktop, any reason for you to stick to IE 8 and not update? (Besides of course using an alternate browser if possible.)

Answer (score -1):

I found a good tutorial about how to fix that. Look under the "Windows" section:

http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95346

Then you'll never have to use Internet Explorer.

But no kidding, I think the link http://browse.azamaraclubcruises.com/shoreExcursions/brochure/view.do doesn’t work for any browser. Seems like a server-side problem.

Comment: So your answer is "Switch to Chrome"?  The server does work; See comments on original question.

Comment: Well... last night the server was down. But Yeah, my answer is "Switch to Chrome".